# How to use a new database on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

Originally when I provisioned a database on Heroku (free one), then I my app got a new environment variable called `DATABASE_URL` that points to a newly created database and my app uses this one.

Today when I provisioned a new database on Heroku (paid) via the UI, I got a new environment variable called `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL` that points to new database.

How do I point my Heroku app to this newly provisioned database `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL`?

I expected my database URL to be swapped with `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL` but that didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This happens when your app has multiple databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):

> As part of the provisioning process, a `DATABASE_URL` config var is added to your app’s configuration. `DATABASE_URL` contains the URL your app uses to access the database. If your app already has a Heroku Postgres database and you’ve provisioned *another* one, this config var’s name instead has the format `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>_URL` (for example, `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL`

You can [promote your new database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-promote) to make it the primary database:

> `pg:promote` updates the value of the `DATABASE_URL` config var with the newly promoted database’s connection string. It also creates an alternate attachment for the old primary database, assigned with a new `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color>_URL` config var. The promotion process triggers a release and restarts the app.

For example:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL -a your-app
```

You should continue to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to connect to your database.