# Rails, Postgres, Heroku: Cannot Commit, Migrate, or Seed To Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

Can't do anything with Heroku using Rails and Postgres. It was working a few days ago and I upgraded from the Free plan to the Mini postgres plan and from the Free dyno to the Eco dyno.

I get this error. I've already tried create a user, role, and database, named vwwaspiwhqdnqp and gave it a password. I also tried setting the credentials via heroku pg:credentials commands. Not sure what is wrong. Thanks for your help!

```
default: &default   
  adapter: postgresql   
  encoding: unicode   
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %> 
    
production:   <<: *default   
  database: vwwaspiwhqdnqp   
  host: localhost   
  port: 5432   
  username: samtimus   
  password: '123'   
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

`heroku pg:promote DATABASE_URL -a ecommercesam`
results in
Unknown database: DATABASE_URL. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL

The error when doing `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL -a ecommercesam`

"Ensuring an alternate alias for existing DATABASE_URL... done Not found"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `production` and `development` configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have multiple `production` and `development` configurations? The closest production configuration here is the one that's nested inside your `development` configuration. But you won't be able to use `trust` authentication on Heroku.

Move that configuration outside of `development` and overwrite the other `production` configuration. Make sure *not* to copy the `POSTGRES_AUTH_METHOD`.

And don't use `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL` directly. If that's the database you wish to use, [promote it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74716109/354577), then use `DATABASE_URL` instead.

Comment: So something like this? The heroku promote command results in Not found, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6eZRYtg.png "Ensuring an alternate alias for existing DATABASE_URL... done 
Not found"

Comment: @sam, again, _please don't post images of text_. Please read [the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577) I shared in my earlier comment. You can edit your question and add it there as text.

Comment: Sorry about that, so I have the folllowing:

`default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

  production:
  <<: *default
  database: vwwaspiwhqdnqp
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: samtimus
  password: '123'
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>`

And the error "Ensuring an alternate alias for existing DATABASE_URL... done Not found"

Comment: Thank you, but again, please _edit your question_ and put the information there. YAML is whitespace-sensitive, so cramming it all into a comment doesn't work. Also, questions should contain all relevant information. Comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had to point the db to a different name according to the db settings I have on heroku! Thanks for your help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).